# move an item from one array to another

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mobile, uikit

So im having a lot of trouble trying to move an item from inside an array to another what i have is a class that englobes 2 arrays one for the cart page and one for the wishlist i want to be able to move these items freely between the 2 arrays. these arrays have a product inside that follows a struct.

```
import UIKit

final class SneakersTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    private let productImageView = UIImageView()
    private let categoryLabel = UILabel()
    private let nameLabel = UILabel()
    private let priceLabel = UILabel()
    private let sizeLabel = UILabel()
    private let colorLabel = UILabel()
    private let removeButton = UIButton()
    private let clearImage = UIImage(named: "Image-1")
    let qtyButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    private let arrowQty = UIImage(named: "Arrow_Qty")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    private let wishButton = UIButton()
    let orderSummaryCell = OrderSummaryCell()

    var removeMe: ((SneakersTableCell) -> ())?
    
    var viewModel = CustomViewModel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle,reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: .default,reuseIdentifier: "SneakersTableCell")
        print("New cell has been create")
        setupUI()
        setupConstraints()
        removeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removeButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func removeButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Tapped remove button")
        // call the closure
        removeMe?(self)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func configure(product: BagProduct) {
        productImageView.image = product.image
        categoryLabel.text = product.category
        nameLabel.text = product.name
        priceLabel.text = "\(product.price)€"
        sizeLabel.text = "Size: \(product.size)"
        colorLabel.text = "Color: \(product.color)"
    }
}
```

the code up ahead shows where i have the wishButton.

```
import UIKit

protocol BagProduct {
    var image: UIImage { get }
    var category: String { get }
    var name: String { get }
    var price: Double { get }
    var size: Int { get }
    var color: String { get }
}
protocol WishProduct {
    var image: UIImage { get }
    var category: String { get }
    var name: String { get }
    var price: Double { get }
}

struct WishProducts: WishProduct {
    let image: UIImage
    let category: String
    let name: String
    let price: Double
    
    init(image: UIImage, category: String, name: String, price: Double) {
        self.image = image
        self.category = category
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
}
    
struct BagProducts: BagProduct {
    let image: UIImage
    let category: String
    let name: String
    let price: Double
    let size: Int
    let color: String
    
    init(image: UIImage, category: String, name: String, price: Double, size: Int, color: String) {
        self.image = image
        self.category = category
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.size = size
        self.color = color
    }
}
```

this is the struct.

```
class Sneakers {
    static let shared = Sneakers()
    var bagProducts = [
        BagProducts(image: UIImage(named: "Image")!, category: "Men", name: "Adidas Gazelle", price: 100.00, size: 40, color: "Blue"),
        BagProducts(image: UIImage(named: "Image")!, category: "Men", name: "Adidas Gazelle", price: 100.00, size: 40, color: "Blue"),
    ]
    
    var wishProducts = [
        WishProducts(image: UIImage(named: "AdidasGalaxy")!, category: "Women", name: "Adidas Galaxy 6", price: 55.00),
        WishProducts(image: UIImage(named: "NewBalance")!, category: "Men", name: "New Balance BB550", price: 150.00),
    ]
}
```

and finally the class of arrays.

Can u guys think of something i´ve been trying a lot of things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Where is the relevant code? Where do you create an instance of Sneakers and where do you try move objects between the arrays? And please remove irrelevant code like layout stuff and other set up that is not important for the question.

Answer (score 0):

One improvement you can do is to use an enum for both types:

```
struct Shoe {
    var image: UIImage?
    var category: String
    var name: String
    var price: Double
    let size: Int
    let color: String
}

final class Sneakers {
    enum Product {
        case bag(shoe: Shoe)
        case wish(shoe: Shoe)
    }
    static let shared = Sneakers()
    var products: [Product] = [
        .bag(shoe: .init(image: UIImage(named: "Image"), category: "Men", name: "Adidas Gazelle", price: 100.00, size: 40, color: "Blue")),
        .wish(shoe: .init(image: UIImage(named: "Image"), category: "Men", name: "Nike Air", price: 150.00, size: 42, color: "White"))
    ]
}
```

Now you've got both types in the same array.
And if you want to have an array with only one typ then you can just **filter** it.

And I would also try to avoid using shared instances. I can work fine but I would avoid it if possible. Read more here:
https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/avoiding-singletons-in-swift/